# Dynamic Text in Bootstrap Alert

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap alert like so :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
     First Error
</div>
```

My problem is I want to be able to change this text dynamically in my code behind, `c#`. Ideally, I would like to have multiple bullet pointed error messages in one alert like the image below:

[image]

Can anyone provide me with any ideas of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html, have this

```
<div id="BootstrapErrorMessage" runat="server">
</div>
```

and in your code, do this

```
....
MyErrorString += "<li>Bad Password</li>";
....
MyErrorString += "<li>Invalid Date</li>";
....
if (!MyErrorString.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    BootstrapErrorMessage.InnerHtml += "<a href=\"#\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">&times;</a>" +
                                       "<ul>" + MyErrorString + "</ul>";
    BootstrapErrorMessage.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-danger";
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to make it so that the alert does not even appear at all unless you actually add something to it.  Basically the div in the html ends up just being a place holder where you will put an error message.  The code adds the bootstrap necessary elements, if there is a need.  Otherwise you have an empty div that does not show to the user.

Comment: codeBoy - would appreciate a vote-up if you think the answer deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the error messages to the client when he request the model of your page(recommended solution). Or you can post your data to the server and get list of errors to show.

Your html code should be like this:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
        <ul>
            <li><strong>First</strong> Error </li>
            <li>Second Error</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And each li element should be updated from server(One of the options you choose).